# How do I change the text content of a div for a comment validation error message?

Tags: html, validation, wp-comment-query

My comment form has validation so that when a user tries to post a blank comment, it currently shows the "This field is required" message under the comment box. How do I change the message content to "Please enter your comment."? I'm guessing that the following line of code might do the trick but I don't know how to nest HTML code in my functions.php file.

```
document.getElementById("comment-error").innerHTML = "Please enter your comment.";
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if your above Javascript is working fine and you want to insert that into a page.

Kindly add the following code to your functions.php.
I have tested this code it's working fine.

```
function handle_comment_error() {
?>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("comment-error").innerHTML = "Please enter your comment.";
    </script>
<?php
 }add_action('wp_head', 'handle_comment_error');
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately, it doesn't work for me . Could it be because the comment form (where the validation error message displays) is in the body of the page and your code tries to add an action to wp_head (the header)?

Comment: no, it's not like that, the wp_head insert script on the top of the page, and that works for all elements doesn't matter that element is on the header/body or somewhere.
Can you please share the link with me to your project?
Or you can check the trigger and can run the above code at that particular time.